# Android: How to use tools with include layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-tools-namespace

How do I use tools:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

With `<include>`?

I have a layout `A` that I use tools to populate all the text fields with test data. And I have layout `B` that use `include` to copy layout A in to it. How ever when I do that I do not see the test data of `A`.

How can I see the test data of `A` included in `B`?

*Both layouts have `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools`, I even pushed it to layout tag.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check this link, [Android tools attributes](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes). It should give you an idea as to how to use the tools attributes.
Specifically look at the `tools:showIn` attribute. It basically allows you to render layout_A in  layout_B, in which layout_B has `<include layout="@layout/layout_A"/>` somewhere in the xml.

Here's an example:

**layout_A**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/layout_B"
    >

<!-- Your layout code goes here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

**layout_B**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

<include layout="@layout/layout_A"/>

<!-- Your layout code goes here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes. I pulled this code from a project I'm working on. I just changed the names of the layouts. Can you post your code?

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 0):

add *layout_width* and *layout_height* to the **include** tag , otherwise you will find it difficult to arrange it in an RelativeLayout