# How to show a fragment layout within a FrameLayout in Android Studio's Layout Editor / Preview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-framelayout, android-layout-editor

I have an empty `FrameLayout` in an `Activity`'s xml file.  I add a `Fragment` to it programmatically in the `Activity` `onCreate()`, and everything is working fine.

However, I want to be able to see a fragment layout in the Preview Layout Editor in Android Studio.

```
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_cities
```

works to show a layout if we are using the `<fragment>` tag in xml, but not for FrameLayout.

Is there a way to show a layout preview in the FrameLayout?

````
// does not work
 <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_cities"
            />
    ```
````

Comment: For testing purpose only you can try Using [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23944452/4168607) but you will have to remove it afterwards .